# Nginx server is treating .js file as static

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, deployment, pm2

I have deployed node app in nginx server, if I browse pointed domain or system IP, server is treating app.js file as static and it is displaying JavaScript content in browser. this is because npm is not started.

Where i have to start npm using pm2 to make it run as node app in bowser instead static.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Did you start your npm server? Can you give the address where your server is running? Where is your nginx pointing to?

Comment: Thanks for your replay @NamanArora. My problem got resolved. I hosted in **usr/share/nginx/app** path but npm was not running. Made it run using pm2 and it is working fine now.